# Hacer Dock adaptable al tamaño del form

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer que el Dock se ajuste al tamaño del form que se muestre, ya que a pesar de que en esta función que estoy utilizando para abrir el form en el Dock lo pongo en Fill, por algún motivo aún se sigue cortando la parte del form que tiene los botones. Esta es la funcion que utilizo para abrir el form al presionar en la opcion de usuarios:

```
 private void abrirForm(IconMenuItem menu, Form formulario)
    {
        if(MenuActivo != null) {
            MenuActivo.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        menu.BackColor = Color.Silver;
        MenuActivo = menu;

        if(FormularioActivo != null)
        {
            FormularioActivo.Close();
        }
        FormularioActivo = formulario;
        formulario.TopLevel = false;
        formulario.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        formulario.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        formulario.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;

        Contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
        formulario.Show();
    }
```

Estas son las propiedades del Dock que tiene en el codigo del Designer.cs

```
   this.Contenedor.AllowDrop = true;
        this.Contenedor.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
        this.Contenedor.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Contenedor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 132);
        this.Contenedor.Name = "Contenedor";
        this.Contenedor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 508);
        this.Contenedor.TabIndex = 3;
        this.Contenedor.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Contenedor_Paint);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Docker

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Diseño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Form en ejecucion

Comment: No entiendo tu problema, las imagenes se ven bien

Comment: La propiedad `Fill` precisamente lo que hace es llenar todo el área de cliente del contenedor, lo que te sucede es que el control `formulario` que estas agregando, cubre toda el área y tus botones, quedan ocultos en segundo plano; cuando tienes varios controles en un mismo contenedor y deseas que se redimensione de manera dinámica, tendrás que usar la propiedad `Anchor`; esto implica que establezcas de forma la propiedad `Size` al momento de agregar tu control `formulario` y la propiedad `formulario.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;`

Comment: Otra variante seria usar un control contenedor, para ello es recomendable un control `TableLayoutPanel`, a ese contenedor agregar el control `formulario` y los botones, en filas y columnas de manera adecuada, según tu diseño. Esta variante es mucho más funcional, más simple de implementar y además bastante elegante.